# Python Auto Setting time against specified

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am using the following code to set the time for each day to midnight, but for some reason it keeps setting the time at a random time I am not sure why.

```
def GetDateTimeFromDate(current_date):
    ret_timestamp = datetime.combine(current_date,datetime.min.time())
    ret_timestamp.replace(minute=0, hour=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    print("5", ret_timestamp)
    return ret_timestamp
```

output is

```
5 2024-01-27 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-01-27 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-01-28 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-01-28 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-01-31 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-01-31 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-01 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-01 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-11 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-11 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-12 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-12 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-13 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-13 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-17 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-17 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-19 00:12:43.145224
5 2024-02-19 00:12:43.145224
```

can someone please help me understand where this time is coming from?

Comment: I'm having a hard time to reproduce; e.g. `datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), datetime.min.time())` gives me `datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 22, 0, 0)` as expected